# Why my 'replace' function failed to replace

Tags: python

I want to replace the "?" with nan so I use the replace function, however it did not work? I can not find the reason?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
adult_data = pd.read_csv('adult data.txt',header=None,encoding='gb2312',delim_whitespace=True)
adult_data.columns = ['age', 'workclass', 'fnlwgt', 'education', 'education_num', 'marital_status', 'occupation', 'relationship', 'race', 'sex', 'capital_gain', 'capital_loss', 'hours_per_week', 'native_country','wage_class']
adult_data.replace('?','Na')
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not assign them, so you would need to change:

```
adult_data.replace('?','Na')
```

To:

```
adult_data = adult_data.replace('?','Na')
```

Or:

```
adult_data.replace('?','Na', inplace=True)
```